# Sending HTML Email using CKEditor and PHPMailer

Tags: header, ckeditor, mime-types, phpmailer, php

I need to send e-mail created with CKEditor and sending it using phpmailer. I use the following code:

```
            $to =$_POST["toEmail"];
    $subject=$_POST["emailSubj"];
    $from=$_POST["fromEmail"];

    $body= $_POST["editor1"];

    $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->From     = "example@example.com";
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject  = $subject;
    $mail->Body     = $body;
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->AltBody="Hello, my friend! \n\n This message uses HTML entities, but you prefer plain text !"; 

    if($mail->Send())
    {
              echo "Message Send Successfully";

            }
```

but i recieved the text like

## hi

etc.. or some time plain text not the html email.

What should I need to do to receive html email.

Answer (score 1):

$mail->IsHTML(true); this line itself ensures that the body will be sent out as an HTML. 
1) Try sending a normal HTML formatted string as an email and check if it works. 
2) echo the $body on the browser and see if it comes up properly. 
3) Not really sure, but this must be an issue with the HTML entities getting encoded so check on those lines.

Comment: Yes, when I echo the $body, it shows well(rendered HTML) on the browser, but when sending the $body through mail, it shows only text not a rendered HTML.